# A lambda with a capture fail to compile when used with std::semi_regular

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

The following example fails to compile as soon as the lambda capture any variable. If the capture is removed the compiler will successfully compile the code below.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
concept OperatorLike = requires(T t, std::string s) {
    { t[s] } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};

template<typename T, typename O>
concept Gettable = requires(T t, O op) { 
t.apply_post(0, op); };

template<std::semiregular F>
class RestApiImpl {
    F m_post_method;
    public:
    RestApiImpl(F get = F{}) : m_post_method{std::move(get)} {}

    template<OperatorLike IF>
    requires std::invocable<F, const int, IF>
    void apply_post(const int req, IF interface){ 
        m_post_method(req, std::move(interface));  
    }
};


int main(){

    int ii;
    auto get = [&ii](int,  OperatorLike auto intf){ 
            std::string dummy = "dummy";
        std::cout << intf[dummy];
    };
    RestApiImpl api(get);
    return 0;
};
```

If the lambda function get() has empty brackets [] , meaning no capture it will compile.

The need of the class `RestApiImpl` is based on following application:

```
class Server{
public:


   struct impl;

   void run(Gettable<impl> auto& api){
      api.apply_post(0, impl(*this));
   }

   struct impl {
        public:
        Server& m_server;
        impl(Server& server ) : m_server(server){}
        std::string operator[](std::string key) {
            return "dummy_for_now";
        }
   };
};

int main(){
    auto get = [&ii](int,  OperatorLike auto intf){ 
            std::string dummy = "dummy";
        std::cout << intf[dummy];
    };
    RestApiImpl api(get);
    
    Server server;
    server.run(api);
    
    return 0;
};
```

The error message:

> :35:24: error: class template argument deduction failed:    35
> |     RestApiImpl api(get);
>       |                        ^ :35:24: error: no matching function for call to 'RestApiImpl(main()::&)'
> :18:5: note: candidate: 'template RestApiImpl(F)->
> RestApiImpl'    18 |     RestApiImpl(F get = F{}) :
> m_post_method{std::move(get)} {}
>       |     ^~~~~~~~~~~ :18:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: : In substitution of
> 'template RestApiImpl(F)-> RestApiImpl [with F =
> main()::]': :35:24:   required from here
> :18:5: error: template constraint failure for 'template  requires  semiregular class RestApiImpl' :18:5: note:
> constraints not satisfied

What options to I have in terms of overcoming this ?`

Comment: Please include error messages...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::semiregular` requires both `std::copyable` and `std::default_initializable`.

`std::copyable` means that it requires the type to be copy-constructible and copy-assignable.

`std::default_initializable` means that it requires the type `T` to have well-formed initializations of the forms `T t;`, `T()` and `T{}`.

A lambda with a capture has a deleted copy assignment operator, no move assignment operator and no default constructor, while for a capture-less lambda (since C++20) all of them are defaulted. As a consequence a lambda with capture is not `std::copyable` (or `std::movable` for that matter) and not `std::default_initializable` and so especially also not `std::semiregular`, while a capture-less lambda is all of these.

Your `RestApiImpl` requires that the passed argument for `F get` in the constructor be `std::semiregular`.

---

To resolve this rethink whether `RestApiImpl` really requires all of these properties of the type.

I can see that it requires move-constructibility in `m_post_method{std::move(get)}`, but it is unclear where it uses e.g. copy-assignability from what you are showing.

`= F{}` uses default-constructibility, but that default value is not used or instantiated if you are not default-constructing a `RestApiImpl` instance with that type.

Then use concepts which are not as restrictive as `std::semiregular`.

If that is not a possibility, then you cannot use a lambda like this directly. Instead you can use an old-style functor type, e.g. a class with overloaded `operator()` and have it store a `std::reference_wrapper<int>` to the `ii` object. This assures assignability, because a simple reference as member would make the class non-assignable.

Comment: "*A lambda with a capture has deleted assignment operators*" This is only true for *reference* captures. Value captures can be assigned to, if the types captured are assignable to.

Comment: @NicolBolas The copy assignment operator is explicitly deleted if there is any capture at all: https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#14.sentence-3

Comment: what options are there to overcome this ?

Comment: @ATK See edit above.

Comment: Thank you. Even when removing the default constructor F{} and the move operator it still does not compile though. What alternatives concepts could I use here ?

Comment: @ATK I did not suggest either of these two things... You need to either replace the `std::semiregular` concept with a weaker one if the design of `RestApiImpl` allows for that or otherwise you need to use a class storing a `std::reference_wrapper` with an `operator()` overload instead of a lambda.

Comment: The Design of ´RestApiImpl´ besically requires that I can use the concept ´OperatorLike´ concept in external functions which only takes that concept argument and invoke the the apply_post on that. What other concept could be used here?

Comment: @user17732522 I added more explanation into how I am intending to use RestAPIimpl

Comment: @ATK What you are showing is independent of the `std::semiregular` concept. Maybe consider why it was put there in the first place. Is there any particular reason? One possible reason would be to enforce that `RestApiImpl` itself is semiregular. Semiregular basically means that a type can be constructed and assigned like built-in scalar types. Is that somehow important for `RestApiImpl`? What does `Gettable<impl>` expect of `RestApiImpl`? If not, what does `RestApiImpl` do with `F` that the concept should constrain? Only move-construct, store and perform calls on it?

Comment: Yes it does look like I chose it initially because it just worked (untill I wanted to capture stuff). 
The only requirement is really that my lambda get is not aware of the OperatorLike implementation, and the Gettable concept is defined above at the start.. It basically list a number of operations it must support (for now just one). And as you the implementation is firstly defined in the `class server` which then passes it the `RestAPIImpl`

Comment: Initially ,  I just implemented my class `RestApiImpl` with template arguments as `template<typename F> class RestApiImpl` and passed the lambda in the constructor. But that did not seem to work either

Comment: @ATK If you don't put a type constraint on `F`, then at least the error message you are getting now about the lambda not satisfying `std::semiregular` should be gone. Whether the lambda will then satisfy all of your other requirements, I don't know. The code in your original question compiles without error if you remove the `std::semiregular` type constraint.

Comment: Ahh yes it actually does - I realized i had another mistake. So what my template argument in `RestAPIimpl` before was a semi_regular it only adds more constrains to the lambda we can pass in?

Comment: @ATK The purpose of type constraints with concepts is to disallow types being passed that don't satisfy the requirements of the constraint. That's meant to give clear and early error messages if you try to use unsupported types with a template instead of having the error show up later deeply nested in some template instantiations. They also clearly state what the semantic requirements on passed types are in the interface. You can also use them to make choices in overload resolution based on which constraints the argument types satisfy. If you don't care about any of that, you don't need them.

Answer (score 2):

If you capture `ii` by reference, the lambda is neither default constructible nor copyable. The `std::semiregular` concept requires this tough.

The template parameter deduced for `RestApiImpl` does not fulfill the requirements imposed on it.